# Are there identities on integers that be proved by checking finitely many cases?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof

Some time ago, I needed to prove some [identity on binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients). Something similar to the following:

$$\sum_{m=0}^n \binom m j \binom {n-m}{k-j}= \binom {n+1}{k+1}$$

but with somewhat different coefficients. I could not find a formal proof, but I computed the values for $j,k,n$ up to 1000 and found that it holds.

Now, I know that formally this is not sufficient for a proof, since the the identity might fail on 1,001. However, the identity looks so "simple" (in that it uses only multiplications and additions - no roots, prime numbers etc.), that it seems impossible that it would start failing after 1,000.

Is there a way to make this intuition formal? I.e., is there a class of identities on integers that are considered so simple, that proving an identity from that class for sufficiently many integers is sufficient for proving that it holds for all integers?

Alternatively, is there a binomial identity of a similar simple form, which is known to hold up to some very large integer, but fails afterwards?

Comment: How does the fact that something is "simple" relieve us from having to ask whether it is true for integers larger than 1000 (or 10000 or wherever you stop checking)? It seems to me the way you would say you don't have to check any more cases is you would exhibit the general proof, thereby making all that case-checking a waste of effort. If the identity is "simple" enough then the proof might be relatively trivial, but it would still be a general proof.

Comment: I suspect that the classic "strong law of small numbers" sequence [OEIS link](https://oeis.org/A000127) could be generalized to produce a family of identities that fail for arbitrarily high values

Comment: On the subject of patterns that fail to generalize, the [Borwein integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral) are an interesting example

Comment: Regarding my first comment: if we define $\binom nk = 0$ for $k > n$, then 
$$
2^n = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom nk
$$
gives us a family of identities that seem to hold, but fail for $n >  m$.

Comment: @DavidK I thought that maybe there is a "meta-theorem" that says that, for every identity of a certain format, if it is true for 1000 different integers then it is true for all integers.

Comment: One approach to making something like this work is to think of the identity as an equality of [bivariate generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Bivariate_and_multivariate_generating_functions). In this framework, the question becomes one of "how many coefficients (i.e. partial derivatives at a point) need to be tested before we can guarantee that two bivariate, analytic functions (satisfying certain conditions) are necessarily equal"?

Comment: Another instance of something like this happening is the fact that two polynomials of same degree are the same iff they agree on at least degree+1 many points. So in some cases it is indeed possible, that one can deduce equality of two functions from them agreeing on a finite subset...

Comment: In principle you could use that fact about polynomials to prove an identity that had, for example, $\binom{n+1}{1000}$ on the right hand side (but not $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ as in the question). It's not hard to show that this is a polynomial of degree $1000,$ so if you have something on the left that is also verifiably a polynomial of degree $1000,$ you only need to check $1001$ data points.